# Javascript Object is pushing on both indexes rather than specific index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I searched this a lot on `stackoverflow` before posting this ticket so please don't consider this as duplicate question.

I have scenario of an `array` with two items, I am pushing an `object` at `index` `1` but it's pushing same `object` on both `indexes`.

**Extra Object**

```js
const extraObj = {
    "item_id": "4",
    "item_name": "Extra Patty",
    "item_image": "placeholder_img.jpg",
    "item_price": "3.00",
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "currency_symbol": "$",
    "gst_fee": "0.00",
    "item_quantity": "1",
    "branch_id": "1",
    "is_type": "extra"
};
```

**Items Array**

```js
const itemsArr = [
    {
        "item_id": "3",
        "category_id": "12",
        "item_name": "Waffles",
        "item_image": "item_081220170335.jpg",
        "is_variant": "0",
        "item_price": "7",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "gst_fee": "0.00",
        "item_quantity": "1",
        "branch_id": "1",
        "is_type": "item"
    },
    {
        "item_id": "3",
        "category_id": "12",
        "item_name": "Waffles",
        "item_image": "item_081220170335.jpg",
        "is_variant": "0",
        "item_price": "7",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "gst_fee": "0.00",
        "item_quantity": "1",
        "branch_id": "1",
        "is_type": "item",
    }
];

itemsArr[1].extras = [extraObj];

// result
[
    {
        "item_id": "3",
        "category_id": "12",
        "item_name": "Waffles",
        "item_image": "item_081220170335.jpg",
        "is_variant": "0",
        "item_price": "7",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "gst_fee": "0.00",
        "item_quantity": "1",
        "branch_id": "1",
        "is_type": "item",
        "extras": [
            {
                "item_id": "4",
                "item_name": "Extra Patty",
                "item_image": "placeholder_img.jpg",
                "item_price": "3.00",
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "currency_symbol": "$",
                "gst_fee": "0.00",
                "item_quantity": "1",
                "branch_id": "1",
                "is_type": "extra"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item_id": "3",
        "category_id": "12",
        "item_name": "Waffles",
        "item_image": "item_081220170335.jpg",
        "is_variant": "0",
        "item_price": "7",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "gst_fee": "0.00",
        "item_quantity": "1",
        "branch_id": "1",
        "is_type": "item",
        "extras": [
            {
                "item_id": "4",
                "item_name": "Extra Patty",
                "item_image": "placeholder_img.jpg",
                "item_price": "3.00",
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "currency_symbol": "$",
                "gst_fee": "0.00",
                "item_quantity": "1",
                "branch_id": "1",
                "is_type": "extra"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

```
case SET_FOOD_EXTRAS:
   const { itemId, extra, extraIndex, itemIndex } = action.payload;
   const cloneItems = cloneDeep([...state.items]);

   // cloneItems.splice(itemIndex, 0, { extras: [extra] });
   cloneItems[itemIndex].extras = [extra];

   return {
     ...state,
     items: cloneItems,
     summary: setSummary(state, cloneItems)
   };
```

Comment: This can happen but not with your current code. If you create an array like `const items = [a, a];` where `a` is some other object, then adding something to `items[1]` will change `a` and therefore also add it to `items[0]`. To prevent this you need to create copies. Also, "please don't consider this as duplicate question" will not protect your question from getting closed a dupe it we find one.

Comment: The solution is to rethink your data structures. One way is to not put the actual item in your array but just its `item_id`. `[ { item_id: 3, extras: []}, { item_id: 3, extras: [12] }]` Or you create copies. Instead of pushing `wafflesObj` to your items array you push `{...wafflesObj}`, which creates a shallow copy.

Comment: I made a copy of an array using `lodash` `cloneDeep` function but it won't worked for me.

Comment: Ok, so given that the code in your question doesn't reproduce the issue anyway, why not show us your actual React lodash attempt?

Comment: @ChrisG but i need to send whole because with that I am creating app with redux to handle all the data at one place once I done with cart thing then i am posting that data to API.

Comment: You say that like my method prevents that from happening, but it doesn't. Keeping just the ids simply means you need to compose the entire object at a later time.

Comment: @ChrisG edited my question look at case code.

Comment: if that's still not clear I am gonna make it work on codepen.io

Comment: yes you are right I can do that by keeping only `ids` in an `items` `array` and then populate `extraItem` by id.

Comment: The cloning creates a cloned array where both elements are again the same object. You need to clone the individual items: https://jsfiddle.net/b0xoz2qe/

Comment: It should work if you do this instead: `const cloneItems = state.items.map(item => cloneDeep(item));`

Comment: Thank you for trying to solve my problem but I am still unable to figure out. Because you said cloning `[{obj}, {obj}]` will work but in my case I want to make `extras [Object]` dynamic I want to push many items into extras so I have to make clone every time?

Comment: No, you only need to shallow-copy the main food items when adding them (using `{ ...obj }` instead of `obj`). You can then add as many extras as you like. You don't have to clone the extras.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you populate your `itemsArr`.

If you do something like:

```js
const ob1 = {
        "item_id": "3",
        "category_id": "12",
        "item_name": "Waffles",
        "item_image": "item_081220170335.jpg",
        "is_variant": "0",
        "item_price": "7",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "currency_symbol": "$",
        "gst_fee": "0.00",
        "item_quantity": "1",
        "branch_id": "1",
        "is_type": "item"
    }
itemsArr.push(ob1);
itemsArr.push(ob1);
```

Then, both items in the array point to the same object so any modifications to one will be reflected on the other.
One solution is to make copies of the object:

```js
itemsArr.push({...ob1});
itemsArr.push({..ob1});
```

Comment: I agree but my scenario is different. Even if I am pushing `a` on index 1 it pushing on both indexes.